# Recurring event log corruption on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, corruption

I didn't get any help on the TechNet forum so I'm going to try my luck here :).



Our web server is running Server 2008 SP1, 64-bit Standard Edition. For the past week or so, we've been experiencing repeated corruption in the Application event log. Each time, we can fix the corruption by clearing the log. But the corruption always comes back, sometimes within an hour or two.

We have a PowerShell script which checks the event log periodically and emails us about error events. Once the log has become corrupt, running "get-eventlog Application" from PowerShell produces the following output:

Get-EventLog : Cannot read log entry number 696.  The event log may be corrupt.
At line:1 char:13
+ get-eventlog  <<<< Application

Usually there are several valid event log entries displayed before the corruption error.

The other event logs (System, Security, and so on) are not experiencing this corruption.

If I look at the Application log in the event viewer, I see several events with no information at all. In the list view, they show the "information" icon, but all other columns are blank. In the "general" and "details" tabs, everything is blank.



I thought about disk corruption. But since this is only affecting the event log, I'm skeptical that the disks are the cause. The server has a single RAID-1 array which shows a status of healthy. Write caching is disabled. All applications and sites hosted on the server appear to be working fine; only the event log is having problems.

On TechNet, someone replied saying it sounded like a PowerShell problem - but it isn't, since the corruption is also visible through the Event Viewer GUI.



I'd appreciate any ideas you might have for finding the cause of this problem...

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: As any application can write (and decide what) to that log it might be one of the running apps that is causing the problems somehow...

Comment: Thanks Oskar. The server is running our custom .NET web apps... if any of them write to the event log, they would be using the standard .NET API for that. I hope it isn't possible to corrupt the event log that way - hopefully the API validates the input and prevents corrupt data from getting in. But you're right, we should definitely take a look at our apps and see what they're writing.

Comment: Hi Richard, I realize this is an old post, but did you ever find a resolution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Per Oskar Duveborn's suggestion try disabling applications to see if you can isolate one causing the log corruption. Is there any pattern to good logs just before it goes corrupt?
2. Maybe there is something wrong with hard drive or location the Event Log being stored at, which causes the corruption. See [kb 315417](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315417) to try moving it to a different folder, or better yet, a different hard drive. At least temporarily to see if that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jack - these are both good ideas. We saved all the corrupt event logs every time we cleared it - so I'm going to go back over them and try to find a pattern. Also, I'll try moving the event log files as you suggested.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2):

Richard

Any pattern in the system log ?

Also try using dumprel.exe to read the corrupt log files.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129266

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. We've actually been busy with a ton of other things so we haven't had time to finish investigating this... but I didn't know about that DUMPEL tool and it definitely sounds useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this patch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2701799